# For what does "key too large to index" warning of mongodb exist?

Tags: mongodb

I'm making a blog using mongodb.

```
const post = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true, unique: false},
    dateCreated: {type: Date, required: true, unique: false},
    dateUpdated: updatedDataSchema,
    content: {type: String, required: false, unique: false},
    tag: {type: String, required: false, unique: false},
    belongToMajor: {type: String, required: true, unique: false},
    belongToMinor: {type: String, required: true, unique: false},
});
```

Above is my schema and the 'content' will necessarily have a large value that is over 1KB if the length of a post isn't short.

And mongodb spits an error like this.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing  1469 { : "very very long statement..." }

I know that I can evade this warning if I set `failIndexKeyTooLong` into false, but I'm not sure if there remains a potential problem if I do so.

So what I mainly want to know is this : Why does mongodb restrict the size of a key?

Comment: Please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit

Comment: Then, isn't there any way to make mongodb create an index if the size of the key is over 1KB?

Comment: Why do you want to index the content of your posts? And what king ot index do you use to do this ?